# Insert element into a sorted array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a sorted that I need to insert elements and keep it sorted to subsequents `binary-search`es calls. What algorithm should I use? or maybe is this a premature optmization and I should to just insert the element and call shell-sort(that I will to implement as replacement to current)?

If this information is useful: the number of elements may be big really.It's truely variable,can hold 1 to 10 or even 1 to 1000+ elements. If you are curious why this is too many variable, I'm writing a parsing.

Comment: The AA tree don't seems be easy to implement. I have an array of integers only.

Comment: Don't need the dowvotes. Even the duplicate question isn't so clear.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of your array can't fit any more entries you will need to allocate another bigger array, move all the entries up to the position where your new entry would go, put your entry there and finally move the remaining entries one position higher than they were. After that you can free the older and now too small array and keep the new one. You can use `memmove` or `memcpy` to do it.

Doing this, when you need to allocate a new bigger array you should allocate it a bit bigger than you immediately need (a multiple of a memory page size would be good), otherwise all the allocating and freeing is going to be costly.

Example:

```
int *array[] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;

// To insert 1 for example you will have to do...
int *new_array[] = malloc(4*sizeof(int)); // Just for the example I make a tight fit, on the code you should allocate it a bit bigger if you expect more inserts to avoid unnecessary mallocs and frees

memmove(new_array,array,sizeof(int)); // Moving the 0
new_array[1] = 1; // Inserting the new element
memmove(new_array[2],array[1],2*sizeof(int)); // Moving the 2 and 3

free(array); // Get rid of the old array
array = new_array;
new_array = NULL;
```

Comment: Using `realloc()` can save you some of the copying (but it is probable that copying will be done).

Comment: Actually,I'm looking for an implementation that perform some swaps in the elements of array itself,something like bubble sort algorithm does. This may be more efficient than make a new array by `malloc()`.Anyway,thanks for your reply.